# Invalid array length, expected integer literal

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, memory

I'm trying to declare an in-memory array with a fixed length:

```
uint length = 10;
uint[length] memory priorityList;
```

However, it just displays this error message:

> Invalid array length, expected integer literal

Do I have to do `uint[10] memory priorityList;` or is there a way I can still use a variable to declare the size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays):
Creating arrays with variable length in memory can be done using the `new` keyword. 
You can use following code snippet to solve your problem.

```
uint length =10;
bytes memory priorityList= new bytes(length);
```

Answer (score 14):

Generally for an array, you would use `uint[] memory list = new uint[](some_size);`